# .htaccess doesn't work on Debian 7 apache2

Tags: apache2, debian

I changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. I did the `a2enmod rewrite` in the terminal and I restarted apache2... but my `.htaccess` file doesn't work.

Command `a2enmod rewrite`

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Command:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Are you sure you've named your file correctly, i.e `.htaccess` instead of `.htacess` as your post seemed to suggest?

Comment: What version of your apache?
There is a new directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:  `Require all denied` .
[Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html)